# Start animation alongside startActivity

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an animation that I want to run at exactly the same time a new activity loads. Its a circle expanding-animation that surrounds the expansion of the next activity. At the moment the circle animation runs, and then the activity loads. I want to do both at the same time.

Here is my current code:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), RequestHolidayActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra(Keys.HOLIDAY, "whatever");
 startActivity(intent);
 revealYellow(event.getRawX(), event.getRawY());
 getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
```

Here is the animation code:

```
private void revealYellow(float x, float y) {
    animateRevealColorFromCoordinates(animateView, R.color.Banksy, (int) x, (int) y);
}

private Animator animateRevealColorFromCoordinates(ViewGroup viewRoot, @ColorRes int color, int x, int y) {
    float finalRadius = (float) Math.hypot(viewRoot.getWidth(), viewRoot.getHeight());
    Animator anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(viewRoot, x, y, 0, finalRadius);
    viewRoot.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), color));
    anim.setDuration(500);
    anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    anim.start();
    return anim;
}
```

How do I get the animation and the startActivity to run concurrently?

Comment: You can place the animation in the onCreate of the second activity

Comment: I want the animation to happen on the first activity

Comment: Well then what do mean by starting another activity, at a time only one activity can be active

Comment: Okay so basically I want a custom transition where a circle surrounds the expanding animation of the app. There doesn't appear to be any way to do this so the idea I have is to implement an expanding circle on the first activity and have the second activity load within that circle.

Comment: You can disable activity transition animations, and use a transparent background to display your second activity. [This Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPxkoe2MraA) has a good example of how to do this. the animations are then implemented in each activity separately using ObjectAnimator class.